# C++ keyword operator on "this" pointer

Tags: c++, this, operator-keyword

Struggling to understand this syntax that I've run across in open source code:

```
/// cast *this into an gpstk::RinexNavData.
/// @throw if the record is invalid or not an ephemeris (isNav()==false)
operator RinexNavData() throw(gpstk::Exception);

/// cast *this into a gpstk::RinexObsData
/// @throw if the record is invalid or not an observation (isObs()==false)
operator RinexObsData() throw(gpstk::Exception);
```

If I interpret the comment correctly, it is changing the type of the object via the "this" pointer.  But this appears to be done via an operator?  Can't hit on a good web search that involves the keyword "this".  Looking for a reference or explanation on how this use of "operator" works.  Web search of C++ operator doesn't lead to anything like this, that I've found so far.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: Perfect.  Thank You.

Comment: this is a quite exhaustive q&a on operator overloading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading you will also find a section on conversion operators

Comment: well I didnt mean this "this" but just this...whatever...

Comment: @freim: I thought your answer was good and presented a useful example - would you consider undeleting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't overthink the use of `this` here; `*this` just means "the current object", so the programmer is using a shorthand to describe what the operator does.

Indeed, like any [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator), it takes the current object and provides a means to *convert* it to a different type.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `this` is not converted. A new object is created (from `this`) via the cast operator, but I would expect `this` to remain unchanged. That in turn begets the question why the operator is not marked `const`, but that's a new discussion.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: `this` is certainly not converted. In C++ parlance, though, `*this` is - making a copy is part of the conversion procedure (it happens every time you make a value cast!). Indeed you cannot transform an object to a different type in-place.